# How to do a href to another wordpress php file?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a question, im working with wordpress, im using stackers a blank theme which im using to convert a html template to wordpress, so bassically im trying to make it work a href to a link of my website, for example, im doing a landing page, and i want a hiperlink or a button to redirect to another php file, for example localhost/wordpress/newpage, what is the correct way to tell wordpress hey i want you to carry me to this file  ';what i need, i need to redirect from home.php to another file loading javascript and css styles similar as normal html hiperlink instancing, how can i achieve it using wordpress and raw code?  image here:[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooypA.png)

file tree here:
so you can make a idea of what im doing(bassically i copy pasted the html template in the home.php file, leaving header and footer quiet....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz0vT.png)

loaded css and javascriph as usual using the functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_enqueue_styles');

 
function theme_enqueue_styles(){

#<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/bootstrap.min.css');
#<!-- Owl Carousel CSS -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/owl.carousel.min.css');
#<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/font-awesome.min.css');
#<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'stylemain', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/style.css');
#<!-- Google Fonts -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'googlefonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/googlefonts.css');
#<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
wp_enqueue_style( 'magnificpopup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/css/magnific-popup.css');
}




function enqueue_my_javascripts_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('magnificpopupinitialization', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/magnificpopupinitialization.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    #wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true); backup
    wp_enqueue_script('navbar', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/navbar.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerycounto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.countTo.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerytyper', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.typer.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('owlcarousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('tiltkquerymin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/tilt.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('mainjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/main.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('particles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/particles.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('magnificpopup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_my_javascripts_scripts');
```

what i want is to use a button or a link to send me to another php page for example im on home.php and i want to go to > about_us how can i achieve it? im a rookie in wordpress so that is why im looking for assistance here,

thank you everyone in foward

Comment: Hello welcome to the stackoverflow.. what you are trying to do is can be done easily by using pages and posts in wordpress i recommend you read the wordpress documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

Comment: Use `<a href="<?php echo site_url()?>/home">Read More</a>`

Comment: So I can create a new php File or How it is the workflow? Thank you, darsh

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding about what pages and posts are in Wordpress. There is no need to create another php file as you suggest. Depending on your theme, a post will be displayed  using a common php file, often single.php which is called with various parameters. A good read of the link given by @Darshkhakhlhar should help.

Comment: Minal Chauhan answer helped me, I created a new page using WordPress but it only shows the footer good and the plain code  how do I get to show it properly, like home.php shows correctly with css and Javascript code? How can I do that to my WordPress page created from *add page* label? Tried looking to darsh answer but found nothing useful could help me, please Someone help me and thank you in forward

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is:

Use `<a href="<?php echo site_url()?>/home">Read More</a>`

Thank you very much @MinalChauhan